# HTML5 localStorage design questions

Tags: database, json, html, local-storage, key-value

What is the best way to store object data in HTML5's localStorage. I haven't worked much with key value storage.

In my research i've seen a few different approaches.

example data:

```
var commands = [
  {invokes: 'Window', type: 'file', data: '/data/1'},
  {invokes: 'Action', type: 'icon', data: '/data/2'},
  {invokes: 'Window', type: 'file', data: '/data/3'}
];
```

Approach 1: store keys that represent each data item

```
// for(...) {
localStorage["command[" + i + "].invokes"] = command[i].invokes
localStorage["command[" + i + "].type"] = command[i].type
localStorage["command[" + i + "].data"] = command[i].data
//}
```

Approach 2: keys is entity name, store json

```
localStorage["commands"] = JSON.stringify(commands);
```

Second approach would require a JSON.parse().

pros/cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record I went with approach 2. My key is similar to a table name, the value is a json stringified array of records. When retrieving the table you must call JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

technologies for local storages are: http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2011/02/client-side-storages-with-html-5.html...

Approach 2, OK..
there are more ways

Answer (score 0):

Certainly your approach works just fine however it does leave you a bit stuck with the convention you chose moving forward.  I would recommend that you consider wrapping your localStorage access up in a class so that your convention is isolated to a class as a true convention.

Otherwise should you chose to change ho you approach it you will have implementation code scattered all over your code base.